# SpellChecking not woking for CKEditor3.6.2 in IE9-11 in windows 7

Tags: ckeditor, spell-checking, aspell

In CKEditor 3.6.2 the spell checking is not working in windows 7 in the browser versions IE 9-11.CKE responds with a

"This page cannot be displayed
The window was not opened from another window."

I am using aspell plugin to spellcheck.

can anyone help me how to get out of this

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this issue before a long time ago, it might be known by the aspell plugin devs - but feel free to check up on this with to them anyway ;-)

The most likely solution at http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Spellchecker-Fails-IE9

To quote:

> davebeyer
>   In our case, this wound up being the result of code copied from plugins/aspell/spellerpages/spellchecker.html. Switching references to "opener" (apparently undefined in IE9) to instead call openerWindow() (see below) fixed our problem.
>
> guikubivan
>   In our case, in addition to modifying spellchecker.html, we had to insert a similar function in controls.html and again, replace references to "parent.opener" to openerWindow()
>
> fonji
>   I had to do both modifications and change a little the openerWindow() code:

```
function openerWindow() {
        if (opener && opener.speller)
            return opener;
        if (parent.opener && parent.opener.speller)
            return parent.opener;
        if (parent.parent && parent.parent.speller)
            return parent.parent;
        return undefined;
}
```